# $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n - E} = \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E \subsetneq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector space. Show that $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n - E} = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Well, It is an exercise. Actually I have to prove that $E$ is closed and $\overline {\mathbb{R}^n - E} = \mathbb{R}^n$, the first part I've proven. Can you give me a hint about $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n-E}$?

Maybe I have to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n - E$ is a open set..

Comment: think geometrically: how "large" is the largest proper subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$? Well, it has dimension $n-1$; i.e this is the worst case scenario. So, for simplicity, think of the subspace $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\times\{0\}$. Can you explicitly show the complement of this subspace has closure equal to $\Bbb{R}^n$? Now, how can we reduce the general case to the special case above (keep in mind that linear isomorphisms are in fact homeomorphisms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n - E$. Note that necessarily $v \neq 0$. Then $\lambda v+e \notin E$ for any $e \in E , \lambda > 0$. Now send $\lambda \to 0$ to get a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n-E$ converging to any $e \in E$.

Comment: Well, I guess we have to choose a point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and show that there exists a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n- E$ converging to $x$. What is the relation with your answer?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ either $x \in E$ or $x \in \mathbb{R}^n - E$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n -E$, you can take the constant sequence equal to $x$, if $x \in E$, use my answer above.